# Unable to show a division tag using JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Consider, I've got this code in PHP

```
<?php
if($count==0)
{
?>
<script>
  show_my_div();
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

the `show_my_div()` is supposed to show a division tag. But It doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Does the `<script>` tag get sent to the browser (view source). What does `show_my_div()` contain?

Comment: it contains the script to the show the division tag. The show_my_div() is a custom written scipt which gets executed ONCLICK of a button. Now, i want it to load automatically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard `show_my_div` function in PHP or JavaScript. You'd have to post the content of that function for anyone to help you with it.

Outputting a div is easy in PHP:

```
echo "<div>content</div>";
```

Similarly, it's easy in JavaScript to create a div element and append it to something. Here's raw JavaScript to append a div to the end of the page:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "The content of the div";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

You can append elements anywhere, not just at the end. For instance, suppose I have a div with the id `foo`:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

...and I want to add a paragraph to the end of it:

```
var p, div;
div = document.getElementById('foo');
if (div) { // (Just being defensive)
    p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = "The text of the paragraph";
    div.appendChild(p);
}
```

These things are made easier if you use a JavaScript library like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) to smooth out browser differences and give you some syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming show_my_div exists,

have you tried to add type="text/javascript" to your script tag?

Comment: @1s2a3n4j5e6e7v: It's a good idea anyway. Yes, it's the default in all modern browsers (and now officially the default, as of HTML5), but still...

Comment: I've had problem running js script that came down to not having the type attribute provided..